# Where is "Browse in same window" in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, internet-explorer-8

How in the world do you configure IE8 to NOT open excel documents in its window.

There was a setting ("Browse in same window") in XP under Folder Options > File Types where you could specify the behaviour. Nothing like that exists in Vista/Windows 7. Why is that even the default behaviour? Why yes, I would like to open this excel file in the browser window with no toolbars. /sarcasm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the capability to do this was [removed from the GUI in Windows 7](http://www.windows7taskforce.com/view/1934).

Have a read of the following for instructions on how to change the behaviour via the registry to how you want it:
 - [How to configure Internet Explorer
   to open Office documents in the
   appropriate Office program instead of
   in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162059)
 - [A new
   window opens when you try to view a
   2007 Microsoft Office program
   document in Windows Internet Explorer
   7 or Internet Explorer 8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927009)

Comment: Thanks for the links. The Windows 7 Taskforce website looks like a great place to vent. :D

Answer (score 1):

To freshen and complete this...

This is related to new Excel 2007 behaviour and the second link provided by SIM
worked, it gives you a downloadable FixIt program from Microsoft.

For those who already have the regedit open/quick fix, you simply replace the 00008
with 80000a00 to set it to open in the browser not externally via excel.exe.

This also works in IE9.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Sheet.8]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:00000008
```

I pulled this from an XP machine running Office 2003 and put it in a Windows 7 machine running Office 2003.  This will force Excel to open in Excel rather than inside IE 8.