# "Browse in same windows" in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, browser, window, regedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is “Browse in same window” in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/109733/where-is-browse-in-same-window-in-windows-7)

Hello

I have research on the internet for this solution since 3 days.
But I can't find the solution.

There is one of the solutions is changing registery file options from `regedit`.

like `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Sheet.8] "BrowserFlags"=dword:00000008`

But this isn't work.

What is this problem solution? Is anyone can help?

Regards,
Soner

Comment: "What is this problem solution?"...  What is the question?

Comment: @typoknig Amazingly, googling for the question title yielded useful results.

Comment: Question is "Where is "Browse in same window" in Windows 7"?

Comment: Yes, possible duplicate but noone can answered it :(

Comment: Doesn't [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;162059) work?

Comment: No, i think this is for Windows XP, i can't find it for Windows 7 solution..

Comment: please explain what "this" is...