# How can I stop Office files from opening in Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is “Browse in same window” in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/109733/where-is-browse-in-same-window-in-windows-7)

I am trying to open an Excel file from web based email, and the file keeps opening in a new window of Internet Explorer, instead of the full Excel program. I would prefer not to download the file by clicking save (right now the download prompt is set to open automatically), and simply click the link and have it open in the full Excel program.

I also cannot install anything on this box. A reg key would be super handy too.

How can I stop this behavior in Windows 7?

Comment: You sure it's not your webmail service trying to be helpful by providing a viewer for people who don't have Excel?

Comment: @techie007 Lotus iNotes rarely does anything helpful, but yes I'm sure. It is opening _Excel_ inside of Internet Explorer.

Comment: is there not an option in lotus notes as to extensions and what to do with them?

Comment: @David McGowan Lotes Notes isn't even aware of the file. I get a download prompt, and when I click open it opens in IE.

Comment: Please check if local excel file also opens in IE ? (had to ask...)

Comment: @CharlieRB Wow, that came up in none of my searches. How did you find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: To stop office files from opening in Internet Explorer 8, it is important for you to use the 32-bit version.
The 64-bit version will not care about your new reg entries

CharlieRB found a duplicate to this that showed up in none of my searches, so I'll leave this here in case this searches better.

Take a backup of your registry by doing an export from the file menu of the registry editor before making changes. A link within the question to a Microsoft article solved the problem by adding the following registry keys:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.Document.8]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000024

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.RTF.8]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000024

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.Document.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000024

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.DocumentMacroEnabled.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000024

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Sheet.8]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Sheet.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PowerPoint.Show.8]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:800000A0

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PowerPoint.Show.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:800000A0

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PowerPoint.ShowMacroEnabled.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:800000A0

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PowerPoint.SlideShow.8]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:800000A0

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PowerPoint.SlideShow.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:800000A0

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PowerPoint.SlideShowMacroEnabled.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:800000A0
```

This should take care of more than just Excel.

Comment: Not sure why but IE just started opening everything in the browser. Many places say to make a folder settings change but I do not have that tab when I go there in mycomputer. Thanks for this info. Strange thing, I did just Excel first to test it and it seemed to have fixed all applications.