# Browse Windows Store Apps in a browser?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I browse the Windows App Store outside of Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/490202/can-i-browse-the-windows-app-store-outside-of-windows-8)

I'm more of the 'open many tabs and compare before I choose' kind of browser. I don't like the layout of the Store app and it's hard to browse. Has anyone found an equivalent website that lists it, or perhaps snooped around at the URI it's connecting to?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/490202/can-i-browse-the-windows-app-store-outside-of-windows-8

Comment: Been there ;) http://superuser.com/questions/480904/how-can-i-stop-office-files-from-opening-in-internet-explorer